# !class_exists is not working in magento?

Tags: php, magento

When I run test.php, why always error on !class_exists line?

This is test.php:

```
<?php    //test.php
    require_once './app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);


    require_once("test-class.php");
?>
```

This is test-class.php:

```
<?php    //test-class.php
        if (!class_exists("AClass")) {
            class AClass {
                public function AnAction() {
                   return 123;
                }
            }
         }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the Magento bootstrap *app/Mage.php* [registers an autoloader](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/Mage.php#L53), your call to `class_exists()` triggers attempts to load a class definition for this class. This behavior can be changed by passing `false`:

```
<?php    //test-class.php
    if (!class_exists("AClass",false)) {
        class AClass {
            public function AnAction() {
               return 123;
            }
        }
     }
?>
```

Further, the bootstrap sets up include path arguments for use by the autoloader:

```
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'community';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';
```

Placing your class definition in any of the above directories will allow it to be defined whenever a definition is required.